fn:parse-json and NUL bytes in XPath
I know that XML doesn't allow NUL bytes in it, but I though that it would somehow work with JSON:
parse-json("""\u0000""") => serialize(map{"method": "json"})

output:
"�"

Is it a limitation of my XPath processor or is it normative?

SaxonJS 2.6 powered XPath 3.1 fiddle gives "\"�\"".
BaseX fiddle gives "�".
The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-json says that there is an options map for parse-json with a fallback function and an escape option

Any characters or codepoints that are not valid XML characters (for
example, unpaired surrogates) are passed to the fallback function as
described below; in the absence of a fallback function, they are
replaced by the Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (xFFFD).


So it is normative, but you can around the problem with """\u0000""" => parse-json(map{"escape": true()}) => serialize(map{"method": "json", "use-character-maps": map{"\":"\"}})
